# Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy fails to copy vhd

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

Here is the code:

```
$sas = Grant-AzureRmDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $diskResourceGroup -DiskName $diskName -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read

$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name $storageAccount -ResourceGroupName $storageAccountResourceGroup)[0].Value
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount -StorageAccountKey  $storageAccountKey

$checkContainer = Get-AzureStorageContainer -prefix $blobContainerName -Context $destContext

Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $blobContainerName -DestContext $destContext -DestBlob $blobName -Force
Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState -Container $blobContainerName -Blob $blobName -Context $destContext -WaitForComplete
```

I'm copying a 256GB data disk to blob for DR exercises and it fails with the following log:

`[18:44:22][Step 7/12] Start Copy of VM to storage
[18:44:23][Step 7/12] 
[18:44:23][Step 7/12] ICloudBlob        : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudPageBlob
[18:44:23][Step 7/12] BlobType          : PageBlob
[18:44:23][Step 7/12] Length            : -1
[18:44:23][Step 7/12] ContentType       : 
[18:44:23][Step 7/12] LastModified      : 9/8/2018 10:44:22 PM +00:00
[18:44:23][Step 7/12] SnapshotTime      : 
[18:44:23][Step 7/12] ContinuationToken : 
[18:44:23][Step 7/12] Context           : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext
[18:44:23][Step 7/12] Name              : some-data-disk.vhd
[18:44:23][Step 7/12] 
[19:43:50][Step 7/12] 
[19:43:50][Step 7/12] CopyId                  : 36d3af59-ce10-4e7c-9b98-cb7ab50d1bb7
[19:43:50][Step 7/12] CompletionTime          : 9/8/2018 11:43:49 PM +00:00
[19:43:50][Step 7/12] Status                  : Failed
[19:43:50][Step 7/12] Source                  : https://md-zdj0tc3ldgbq.blob.core.windows.net/px2lhh4
[19:43:50][Step 7/12]                           e75-b63db649096c&sig=NsbVUO5+LQoUnIvCFMKJcKYSJ9DlI7m/
[19:43:50][Step 7/12] BytesCopied             : 75310645760
[19:43:50][Step 7/12] TotalBytes              : 274877907456
[19:43:50][Step 7/12] StatusDescription       : 403 AuthenticationFailed "Copy failed when reading 
[19:43:50][Step 7/12]                           the source."`

It creates a 0 byte blob that is unusable. This used to work before. Does anyone have insight into this error. Should I not be doing this? Is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: Giving your complete command and more details will be helpful.

Comment: I've added my code to the question. I now realize that the actual error is timeout caused by the hour-long access token running out of time. But according to the amount of data backed up, it should take this script 4 hours to back up my drive. Is there a better/faster method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the upload is failing due to the fact the file is only available for 3600 seconds:
`$sas = Grant-AzureRmDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $diskResourceGroup -DiskName $diskName -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read`

Changing the amount of time that the file is readable for should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> But according to the amount of data backed up, it should take this script 4 hours to back up my drive. Is there a better/faster method?

In this case, you could try to use [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ffiles%2Ftoc.json) to copy blobs in Blob storage. For very large amounts of data, you can also [Azure Import/Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-import-export-service).

Moving Data FAQ in official doc:

[Can I migrate VHDs from one region to another without copying?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-moving-data?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ffiles%2Ftoc.json#can-i-migrate-vhds-from-one-region-to-another-without-copying)

Comment: Thanks Joy! Not sure if that answers my question but useful enough.